# Change the thickness of an SVG shape

Tags: html, svg

I'm not familiar enough with svg drawing.

I have this arrow in SVG format. How can I increase the thickness of the arrow?

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 50,0 L 60,10 L 20,50 L 60,90 L 50,100 L 0,50 Z" class="arrow" transform="translate(85,100) rotate(180)"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can add a stroke with `stroke="black" stroke-width="10"` and then adjust your viewBox accordingly.

```html
OLD:
<div style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 50,0 L 60,10 L 20,50 L 60,90 L 50,100 L 0,50 Z" class="arrow" transform="translate(85,100) rotate(180)"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
<br>
NEW:
<div style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
  <svg viewBox="-10 -10 120 120">
    <path d="M 50,0 L 60,10 L 20,50 L 60,90 L 50,100 L 0,50 Z" class="arrow" transform="translate(85,100) rotate(180)" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is technically not using CSS.

Answer (score 10):

You can adjust `stroke` and `stroke-width` with CSS:

```
div svg path {
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `stroke` should be the background color and the `stroke-width` between 1 and 2

```
 svg path {
      stroke: #ffffff; /* Background color against your svg */
      stroke-width: 1px; /*Between 1px and 2px*/
    }
```